# Replicate javascript to make requests/arguments to remote server using PHP

Tags: php, javascript, xmlhttprequest

I am building an application that grabs html source from various sites.
Using xpath or simple html dom, I can then quite easily parse this html and dumb it to a database etc.

Unfortunately this approach does not work for one particular site.
This is because the site loads its content with JavaScript and so most of its content is not visible in the html source.

Having googled this over and over and read loads of threads covering the subject here on Stackoverflow. I'm still not sure how to go about solving this problem.

Here is the important part of the code this site is using to display its content.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var example = {

        getServiceCall:function(url) {

     {
        var srtPos=url.indexOf('Filter');
        var endPos=url.indexOf('/',srtPos);
        var filter = $.getUrlVar("Filter");

        var filterInServiceUrl=url.slice(srtPos,endPos).split(":");

        url = (filter) 
            ? url.slice(0,srtPos) + filter + url.slice(endPos,url.length)
            : url.slice(0,srtPos) + filterInServiceUrl[1] + url.slice(endPos,url.length);
     }

      document.writeln('<scri'+'pt src="'+url+'" type="text/javascript"> </sc' + 'ript>');
    },

};

$.extend({
  getUrlVars: function(){
    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
  },
  getUrlVar: function(name){

  }
});

</script>
<div id="content">
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function doPerItem(html){ $("#content").html(html.toString()); }
example.getServiceCall('http://www.example.com/?callback=doPerItem');
</script>
</div>
```

Using Inspect Element in Google Chrome I can see that there is a file that contains html source that I want.

How can I use php to make the same request/arguments to the remote serve and then save the response to a file?

I will then be in a position to parse it with xpath or simple html dom just like the other sites.

Your help will much appreciated.

Comment: Please post the `url` parameter that would get passed in to the `example.getServiceCall` function above

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, lost my internet connection. I heavily edited the code above. Don't want to publish this sort of thing on a public forum. However if this will help. I posted the url parameter above.

Comment: You probably already know this: the url that gets generated is a `jsonp` kind of ajax call. You could read about jsonp here - http://remysharp.com/2007/10/08/what-is-jsonp/ ....

I also have fiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/FloydPink/BSqvU/ that does the url munching from your script above to give the final url that is requested.

Comment: No. I am afraid I didn't know that, nor do I understand it. Going back to my original question. Is it possible to create a php script that will make same request/argument and save the response? Do you need ajax to do this. Please explain as this very new to me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any PHP-based remote access tool (including cURL) which interprets JavaScript. Selenium (normally used for testing) might do this, but Selenium-RC did not work for me at all with PHP and had bugs in the IDE.

You cannot practically use Ajax because that doesn't resolve JavaScript either (maybe you can resolve it somehow with `eval()` which has its security concerns), and JSONP will only work if the remote server is deliberately offering an API for getting its data (you could write your own proxy and then give the data as JSONP but then you'd still have the problem of resolving JavaScript).

What you could do (though **it has real security risks** for your site):

1. Write a file in PHP which simply gets the remote site's contents, using file_get_contents() and then outputs it (i.e., make a proxy).
2. Dynamically insert a hidden iframe via JavaScript to load your proxy page and then wait for the iframe's load event.
3. Get the resulting HTML of the hidden iframe from the parent and send back the result to the server.

You can't avoid step 1 unfortunately because you can't listen in on an iframe unless it comes from the same domain as yours.

Note that if the site you are visiting crafts their JavaScript in a certain way, they could access your containing HTML, and do things like grab your user's cookies so as to steal passwords, find out your domain or what's showing on your page, etc.

There may be better solutions out there, but I'm not aware of any.

Comment: Wow. That's very informative but way out my league to implement. But thanks for the effort anyway.

Comment: With a little investigation of "hidden iframes", it really wouldn't be so difficult to implement, but the bigger problem is that it is not secure...